# Displaying Log file contents on web page

Tags: javascript, php, python, html

I have a script which runs on a remote server , and this script generates a log file. I am calling this script on the server from my PHP command ( exec ) in which i give the credentials and the script name to call .

```
eg : exec( " ssh -i pemfile user@ipaddr ' python script.py' ")
```

this script generates a log file in the remote server which i want to be able to show on my webpage, to give the user an idea of how the script is working and its progress.

i want to mimic the following command , but to display on webpage not on terminal.

```
tail -f log_file.log
```

This is like a UI to call the script and also see the Log file, to know if the script was a success or not .

How do I go about doing this ? 
I am new to front end programming , please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in serveral ways.

For example, You can call the script from PHP and get the result using [shell_exec function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php):

```
<?php 

$command = escapeshellcmd('/usr/custom/test.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;

?>
```

Then, you will have to process the result to generate a view on your website.

Another way is to generate the file on a path in your server where our website has read permissions. For example, using [fgets](https://tecadmin.net/php-read-file-line-by-line-fgets-function/)

Regards.